# Why won't my Olympus OM-D E-M5 turn on?

Tags: repair, olympus

I purchased an Olympus OM-D E-M5 a couple of months ago and it was a fabulous camera until it stopped working. Now when I switch it on, the lense opens and an image appears on the screen. There is no response from the camera buttons and within a few seconds it shuts down automatically. If anyone has any suggestions for a solution I would appreciate it. 
Thanks!

Comment: Try to recharge or change battery

Comment: I have tried charging the battery and it seems fully charged. Would you suggest buying a new one?

Comment: See: http://www.mu-43.com/threads/65378/ maybe?

Answer (score 3):

If you've already:

- charged the battery properly with no results
- Removed the lens and checked/cleaned the electrical contacts on both the lens and the camera mount
- removed the main battery (as well as any small backup battery that allows the camera to maintain settings and time & date when the main battery is removed) and then allowed the camera to sit for several hours before reinstalling the battery

with no change in the camera's behavior then it is time to contact either the seller or the manufacturer.

I would suggest contacting the manufacturer first to see if this is a known issue. There may be a solution that can be fixed by the user following instructions from the manufacturer or the camera may need to be sent in for repair/replacement. If the camera needs to be serviced then you might consider exchanging it where you purchased it if you are still within the seller's exchange period.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION , put the camera on the side and put a few drops of alcohol on the little lever and turn it on several times, then blow the remaining alcohol

Comment: [**Please do *not* serve alcohol to your camera.**](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100761/75526)

Answer (score -1):

Try cleaning the battery contacts, both inside the camera and on the battery