# What does the solution used in DSLR sensor cleaning kits contain?

Tags: sensor, cleaning

What is the actual solution used in DSLR sensor cleaning kits?

Comment: Is DALR a typo (probably?) or a specific cleaning kit?

Comment: Is this just curiousity or do you have a specific problem?

Comment: My money on [isopropyl alcohol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopropyl_alcohol).

Comment: Last time I cleaned my sensor, I used a *couple drops* of distilled water. [Nothing crazy.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100761/75526)

Comment: vtc b/c Not relevant to the *practice* of photography. Not something someone photographers would necessarily be expected to have expertise in.

Comment: I don't know what the kits contain, but isopropanol (ie isopropyl alcohol) works well: I have a lot of the the little prepackaged sachets with isopropanol & tissue to clean anti-newton glass &c and I've used them with success.  The advantage of them is that you are very sure there's no abrasive crud when you open them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking about sensor (really the filter in front of the sensor) cleaning solutions -- such as "Eclipse" ... that's nearly pure methanol.  It is used because it evaporates rapidly and leaves no residue.

See:  https://photosol.com/products/eclipse-optic-fluid/

Comment: Probably also because it's cheaper than Ethanol, which has higher taxes and can be "abused".

Comment: I appreciate the response. The reason for me asking is because I needed to find a local source so I could clean my sensors because of the Black Dot invasion on all of my photos. Unfortunately no one sells locally in New Orleans. I already have the lens cleaning kit, but not the little swabs and the solution. If I would have been able to clean with rubbing alcohol that would have been great but Methanol is not a house hold item and honestly I would not know where to start...
Thank you all.

Comment: If you can find a dedicated camera store (e.g. not a big-box store that also sells cameras) they'll be more likely to have the cleaning solutions & supplies.  You can also order from online vendors.